# g++ comes up with errors when run with execlp, but not from the terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, exec

Using fork() and execlp(), I'm trying to compile a cpp file to a .so.  I'm running a copied g++-4.8 executable that's in my project's directory tree.  When run from the terminal, everything goes smoothly and I end up with a working dynamic library, but when I make a child process and use execlp to do the same thing, I get an error:

```
g++-4.8: error: @@@: No such file or directory
```

This is repeated 6 times with a few characters in the "filename" changed around a bit.  To compare, this is what I write in the terminal:

```
$ g++/bin/g++-4.8 -fPIC -shared bob.cpp -o bob.so
```

...and this is the code that generates the error:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    execlp("g++/bin/g++-4.8", "g++/bin/g++-4.8", "-fPIC", "-shared", "bob.cpp", "-o", "-bob.so");
}
```

bob.cpp is in the working directory of the parent process, and the terminal code is executed from that same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@@` is a typical sequence from the header of a binary (ELF) file. You forgot to `NULL` terminate your argument list to `execlp()`, so it read garbage and tried to pass it to g++.